# Extending phpunit error message

Tags: phpunit

I want to add log output to all test messages.

```
$this->assertTrue(FALSE, "This assertion is False.". myLog::GetErrors());
```

I tried extending the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::assertThat function with my appended message, but it doesn't seem to have an effect on it.  I know the extended PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase works because I have several helper functions (random string generation) in there as well that I use for testing.

Any other thoughts?  Could it be a customer listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the assertions are static methods from `PHPUnit_Framework_Assert` and cannot be overridden by a subclass of `TestCase`. You can define your own assertions that call the originals with an amended message, however.

```
public static function assertTrue($value, $message='') {
    PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertTrue($value, $message . myLog::GetErrors());
}
```

All failed tests call `onNotSuccessfulTest()` with the exception as the only parameter. You could override this method and in some cases add your log errors to the exception's message. Some of the PHPUnit exceptions provide a second description in addition to the error message contained in the exception.

```
public function onNotSuccessfulTest(Exception $e) {
    if ($e instanceof PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException) {
        $e->setCustomMessage(implode(PHP_EOL, 
                array($e->getCustomMessage(), myLog::GetErrors())));
    }
    parent::onNotSuccessfulTest($e);
}
```

**Update:** As Gregory Lo noted in a comment below, `setCustomMessage()` and `getCustomMessage()` were removed in PHPUnit 3.6. :(

Comment: Thanks.  I decided to go with your second suggestion, seeing that I'd rather not rewrite every assertion.

Comment: Where did you get these getCustomMessage and setCustomMessage methods? There's not such methods in PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException

Comment: @GregoryLo Sadly, they were removed in the 3.6 release for no reason I can discern.

Comment: When I get some time I'll create a pull request to add them to the base PHPUnit exception.

Answer (score 0):

In recent PHPUnit Versions it is not necessary anymore.
When you specify the error parameter in an `$this->assertXXXX()` it preceeds PHPUnit's original message.

Screenshot:

[image]