# Rename screenshots taken on failure in PHPUnit Selenium

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

PHPUnit has an option to take a screenshot upon a Selenium test case failure. However, the screenshot filename generated is a hash of something - I don't know what exactly. While the test result report allows me to match a particular failed test case with a screenshot filename, this is troublesome to use.

If I could rename the screenshot to use the message from the failed assert as well as a timestamp for instance, it makes the screenshots much easier to cross-reference. Is there any way to rename the generated screenshot filename at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a modified version of @sectus' answer:

```
public function onNotSuccessfulTest(Exception $e) {
    $file_name = '/' . date('Y-m-d_H-i-s') . ' ' . $this->getName() . '.png';
    file_put_contents($this->screenshotPath . $file_name, base64_decode($this->captureEntirePageScreenshotToString()));
    parent::onNotSuccessfulTest($e);
}
```

Although the conditional check in `tearDown()` works fine, based on [Extending phpunit error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892837/extending-phpunit-error-message), I decided to go with `onNotSuccessfulTest()` as it seemed cleaner.

The filename could not accept colons `:`, or I would get an error message from `file_get_contents`: `failed to open stream: Protocol error`

The function `currentScreenshot` also did not exist, so I ended up taking the screenshot in a different way according to http://www.devinzuczek.com/2011/08/taking-a-screenshot-with-phpunit-and-selenium-rc/.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this (it's works with selenium2):

```
protected function tearDown() {
    $status = $this->getStatus();
    if ($status == \PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_ERROR || $status == \PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_FAILURE) {
        $file_name = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . get_class($this) . ':' . $this->getName() . '_' . date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') . '.png';
        file_put_contents($file_name, $this->currentScreenshot());
    }
}
```

Also uncheck

```
protected $captureScreenshotOnFailure = FALSE;
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, but I never resolved the issue and forgot about it and only came back to it recently. Where can I put your code snippet? It seems like it should be located at the end of test execution, but doesn't PHPUnit return early if there's an error/failure? I'm using Selenium RC btw.

Comment: @xiankai, try to use tearDown method.

Answer (score 0):

Another method I played around with, as I still wanted to use `$this->screenshotUrl` and `$this->screenshotPath` for convenient configuration:

I overwrote `takeScreenshot` from https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php

```
protected function takeScreenshot() {
    if (!empty($this->screenshotPath) &&
        !empty($this->screenshotUrl)) {
        $file_name = '/' . date('Y-m-d_H-i-s') . ' ' . $this->getName() . '.png';
        file_put_contents($this->screenshotPath . $file_name, base64_decode($this->captureEntirePageScreenshotToString()));

        return 'Screenshot: ' . $this->screenshotUrl . '/' . $file_name . ".png\n";
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```